# how to make flash page scroll to top?

Tags: flash

I have an AS2 site where all the pages are different lenghts and have navigation at the top and the bottom.

When you click on the bottom navigation on one of the longer pages in order to get to another shorter page, you land on the same place where the bottom navigation was on the page before; ie you land at the bottom of the page.

How can I get around this so that every time you land on a new page it has scrolled to the top?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript:

```
window.scroll( 0, 0 );
```

Or give the object tag an id as an anchor, and link to it.

```
navigateToURL( new URLRequest( '#top' ) );
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer, but I have not managed to get it working. I am using SWFaddress - do you think this might be why? If so, do you know a way around it? (Please note I am new to programming). Many thanks.